# Not able to get authorization on 2checkout

Tags: node.js, 2checkout

I am trying to authorize orders on the 2checkout sandbox, it was working fine but suddenly it stopped. Now I am always getting:

> Payment Authorization Failed: Please verify your information and try
>   again, or try another payment method.

```
var tco = new Twocheckout({
    sellerId: "1234456688", //on my code I am sending my true seller id                                  
    privateKey: "XXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX", //on my code I am sending my key                              
    sandbox: true
  });

  var plan = SubscriptionService.getPlan(req.body.plan);
  if(plan) {

    var params = {
      "merchantOrderId": new Date().valueOf()+"",
      "token": req.body.token,
      "currency": "USD",
      "tangible": "N",
      "lineItems": [
        {
          "name": plan.name,
          "price": plan.price,
          "type": "product",
          "quantity": "1",
          "productId": plan.id,
          "recurrence": "1 Month",
          "duration": "Forever",
          "description": ""
        }],
      "billingAddr": {
        "name": req.body.ccName,
        "addrLine1": req.body.streetAddress,
        "city": req.body.city,
        "state": req.body.state,
        "zipCode": req.body.zip,
        "country": req.body.country,
        "email": req.user.email,
        "phoneNumber": "5555555555"
      }
    };


    tco.checkout.authorize(params, function (error, data) {
      if (error) {
        res.send(error);
      } else {
        res.send(data.response);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

this is the example of a json I am sending

```
{ merchantOrderId: '1494967223074',
  token: 'ZTFiNmFkMjktZWNmMi00NjlhLWE0MDAtZmJkMGJlYjU5M2Q1',
  currency: 'USD',
  tangible: 'N',
  lineItems:
   [ { name: 'pro plan',
       price: '149.00',
       type: 'product',
       quantity: '1',
       productId: '002',
       recurrence: '1 Month',
       duration: 'Forever',
       description: '' } ],
  billingAddr:
   { name: 'Testing Tester',
     addrLine1: '123 Main Street',
     city: 'Townsville',
     state: 'ohio',
     zipCode: '43206',
     country: 'USA',
     email: 'victor.eloy@landmarkwebteam.com',
     phoneNumber: '55555555' } }
```

If I go to my account >> site management and set demo to true I manage to get authorizations from the sandbox but the orders do not get logged to the sandbox. Previously even when the demo mode was off I managed to get the orders authorized but now I don't know what is happening.

here comes a log from one order:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. Just 4 days ago the code was working fine. I'm assuming it's something from 2checkout not from our code..

Comment: I contacted 2checkout support, they told me they are facing a problem on their end and they don't know how long it will take to fix :(

Comment: I see.. Any idea if this problem will affect live accounts ? Or only hopefully on testing sandbox accounts ?

Comment: Only sandbox accounts are being affected.They fixed the problem today, so it should be working right now.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can see is you are attempting to parse

```
"zipCode": req.body.zip
```

but you are sending

```
 zipCode: '43206'
```

I assume this should be parsed as `req.body.zipCode`

Comment: these values are coming from a form, in my form I am sending the zip code as 'zip'. If you look in the json you will see I am fetching the right value from the form and sending it to 2checkout.

Comment: gotcha. I assumed the section you stated that this is the JSON I'm sending  was what you were sending to your api tp handle the request not what you were sending to 2checkout. apologies.

Comment: I took a look at the sandbox api and it gives fake user data to test with to test errors and successes. I would definitely look at this. Authorize.net and PayPal from my experience do the same thing for sandbox. Pretty much everything will fail accept certain fake data they give you to test with. here's the link https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/sandbox/test-data

Comment: Hi, I already tried with the sandbox test data and still not working. But the weirdest thing is that the exact same code was working 2 weeks ago.